# generate configure.ac and configure script

Tags: configure, autoconf

This is my source tree:

```
                  client (dir with a lot of c files inside)
FTPUtils --> bin /
                 \server (dir with a lot of c files inside)
                |
                 proto.h
                 function.c
```

I've read some autoconf tutorial but i didn't understand how to make a **general** *configure.ac*, *Makefile.am* and *configure* script.
Can somebody explain it to me please?

I also have to add *-lcurl* and *-lcrypto*!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a [tutorial](http://ptomato.name/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/real-life-app-setup.html) on this very subject - it's geared towards GTK programming but the first parts are not GTK-specific, so they will probably get you started.

Comment: I am new to C/C++ and have been thrust into a project where I have to port C code from Linux to AIX. I have started reading through your tutorial, and I am feeling I have hit the jackpot when it comes to building real life complex C programs! Thanks!